# Allow access only to one website

Tags: block

Hey. I'd like to allow access on a computer connected directly to the internet to one website ONLY.

The solution of IE's "Content advisor" or firefox's "FoxFilter" isn't good enough because it actually downloads the data and just don't display it. I want to block the traffic before the requests are sent.

How is it possible?
Thanks.

Edit: OS is windows xp. The browser can be firefox, iexplorer, chrome... It doesn't matter.
The computer is connected directly to the modem.

Comment: It's impossible to give an appropriate answer without knowing what OS the client is running, and whether there are any proxies / firewalls between the client and the internet

Comment: Sorry. Just added those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the proxy of IE to a fake proxy, and add the website you want your users to access in the exception list of that proxy ? that way, no data connection at all, except for the website you choose.

Cost : zero !

Answer (score 1):

You can block websites by adding it to your proxy server, but this requires you to run your own proxy server such as squid.

Another solution can be to block it using firewall such as Linux netfilter. You can block the website IP(s). This depends on the type of router/firewall you have.

This is what I can tell from the provided information.

Comment: The computer is connected directly to the internet. There are no firewalls in between.

Answer (score 0):

As Khaled said, you will need to intercept the data.

This can be done easily with iptables on linux (on host or gateway) :

`iptables -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 64.111.96.38`

This redirects all requests to [Kittenwar](http://www.kittenwar.com/). See [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/341/) for more fun !

iptables can also redirect requests to a proxy :

`iptables -A PREROUTING -s <client network/host> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <proxy @>`

and then [use mogrify to turn upside down or blur images](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) ;)

Edit : 
just saw your update. this will not fit your needs (windows), but could be useful for others or give you ideas.